# Integrating with Facebook Ad Providers in Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I am developing a facebook application. In that application I want to integrate with Ads provided by the Ad Providers. The accepted Ad providers are listed here :http://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/

My question is how do I integrate with Ads provided by Ad Providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to individually establish a relationship with the ad provider you wish to use. Each ad provider will have their own terms for displaying their ads on Facebook, and their own integration instructions.

Open X might be a good one to start with. They don't have any traffic requirements.